# Trying to concatenate to lists from numpy

Tags: python, concatenation, dimensions

```
x1 = np.ones([T])
y2 = 0.7*sp.sin((np.arange(1,T+1)/100))
```

I'm trying to concatenate the above with the line:

```
np.concatenate((x1,y2))
```

But I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       np.concatenate((x1,y2))
>
> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

```
x1.ndim Out[241]: 2

y2.ndim Out[242]: 1
```

why does x1 have 2 dimensions and y2 have 1 dimension?

Comment: Most likely, you screwed up `T` somehow, and `T` is actually an array. It's hard to say with just the code you've posted. You should really make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also what is ``sp``?